# Compiling and using OpenCV

Tags: c++, python, opencv

I have install cmake version 2.8.12 and downloaded opencv-2.4.6.1

I then cd into the opencv-2.4.6.1 directory and run

```
$ cmake CMakeLists.txt 
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Yet I cannot import cv2 in python. CMake, make, and make install run fine, what gives?

I am running Mountain Lion with xCode developer tools installed and python 2.7.2

Comment: Not sure about OSX, but on windows you need to copy python module from build directory to Python's site-packages

Comment: That worked after compiling it in 32 bit mode. Thanks.

Comment: @Igonato: Provide your comment as answer so that questionnaire can accept it and close the session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy compiled module from the `build/python/2.X` to the `/Library/Python/2.X/site-packages/` folder.

Also OpenCV needs to be compiled with same bitness as python.